# Embedded CSS file into a multi-part MIME email

Tags: css, mime, html-email

Is it possible, like for images, to embedded a CSS file into an mutlipart Mime email body message and make reference to that styles within the body of the message using cid: (the same way it is possible for images) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most email clients (like Outlook) are nowhere near standards compliant. I don't know of one that fully support CSS 2. I've never heard of anyone embedding a CSS file inside an email and I doubt it would be very cross-client compatible even if it was possible. Unfortunately, the way to go with emails is old school HTML 4 tables with inline styles. Anything more than that and there will be big differences among the different clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

At least, if I save the following as a [`.mhtml`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) file, and open it in IE or Opera, it works:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html";boundary="----boundary"

------boundary
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=test.html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; name=test.html
Content-ID: <htmlid>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!doctype html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cid:cssid">
This should be red

------boundary
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=all.css
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8; name=all.css
Content-ID: <cssid>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

body{color: red}

------boundary--
```

Whether that means it will also work in e-mail clients is another matter, but I can't see why it would work for image links, but not for CSS links.

Comment: this is a late reply but I suppose it's still valid. Image links are inline elements, while the css link applies to the surrounding document ("browser window") and e-mail clients like to replace that part entirely. So, it would make sense that CSS files cannot be referenced by mime content id, while images can.